# Limit product to specific user role

Tags: woocommerce, user-roles

I have a woocommerce site with two products only, each belonging to their category;

`Category X` must be visible by everyone.

`Category Y` must be limited to users with the user role: practitioner.

How can I:

(1) Make Category Y only visible to `practitioner` user roles

and

(2) Make Category Y visible to all, but only purchasable by `practitioner` user role?

This is my attempt though not working ar expected.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'limit_products_basic', 10, 2 );

function limit_products_basic( $q, $query )
{
 $user = wp_get_current_user();
 if ( !in_array( "practitioner", $user->roles ) ) {
     $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
     $tax_query[] = array(
     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => array( 'app' ),
     'include_children' => true,
     );
 $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
 }
}
```

I know there are lots of plugins that can help to achieve this, but I am hoping to keep it clean and 'simple'.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this brilliant tutorial by Tom Anbinder and this is the result:

```
add_role( 'practitioner', 'Practitioner', get_role( 'customer' )->capabilities );

if ( ! function_exists( 'wpf_is_current_user_role' ) ) {
    function wpf_is_current_user_role( $roles_to_check ) {
        $current_user       = wp_get_current_user();
        $current_user_roles = ( empty( $current_user->roles ) ? array( '' ) : $current_user->roles );
        $roles_intersect    = array_intersect( $current_user_roles, $roles_to_check );
        return ( ! empty( $roles_intersect ) );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'wpf_do_hide_product' ) ) {

    function wpf_do_hide_product( $product_id_to_check ) {

        $products_to_hide  = array( 204,); 
        $roles_to_hide_for = array( 'practitioner' ); 

        return (
            in_array( $product_id_to_check, $products_to_hide ) && 
            !wpf_is_current_user_role( $roles_to_hide_for )         
        );
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'wpf_product_purchasable_by_user_role', PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpf_product_purchasable_by_user_role' ) ) {
    function wpf_product_purchasable_by_user_role( $purchasable, $product ) {
        return ( wpf_do_hide_product( $product->get_id() ) ? false : $purchasable );
    }
}
```

More detail on tom's website: [wpfactory.com](https://wpfactory.com/blog/how-to-hide-products-by-user-role-in-woocommerce/)